# Char-array: replace letter with capital letter in java

Tags: java, foreach

So I want to take this String called navn, and make it into a char-array. Then I want to go through it and replace small "a's" with capital A's. So it should print E S ... l A ...(big A).

But I cannot get it to work correctly. Any help would be great!

```
private String navn = "Espen Askeladd";

public void metode4() {

    char[] navnBlirCharArray = navn.toCharArray();

    for (char output : navnBlirCharArray) {

        if(navnBlirCharArray.equals('a')) {
            navnBlirCharArray[output] = 'A';
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use toUpperCase

Comment: In addition to the other good answers you've gotten, the code `navnBlirCharArray.equals('a')` makes no sense. The `char` will be boxed into a `Character` object, and then you will be comparing a `char[]` object to see if it is equal to a `Character` object. It will, of course, always return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating! Use replace() on your string.

```
    String navn = "Espen Askeladd";
    navn = navn.replace('a', 'A');
    System.out.println(navn);
```

Check the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)).

Answer (score 1):

You are indexing your `char[]` with the `char` instance within your fast-enumeration, which gets boxed as `int` and could very well throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the `int` value of your `char` was `> navnBlirCharArray.length` (a part from the fact that it's not the index you want).

See example here to understand what's happening:

```
String[] foo = {"foo", "bar"};
char c = 1; // valid
System.out.println(foo[c]); // valid too
```

**Output**

```
bar
```

---

Use `String.replace` to replace `char`s or `String`s within your `String`, and `String.replaceAll` to replace by regular expressions.

**For instance**

```
String replacement = input.replace('a', 'A');

or... 

String replacement = input.replace("a", "A");
```

Finally, if you need the whole `String` upper/lower-case, use `String.toUpperCase` or `String.toLowerCase`.

Answer (score 1):

The for-each construct loops over the element values of the array, placing each element in the named variable (in this case, `output`). It is not suitable when you need to modify the array, because for that you need know to the element's index in the array, so you should use a traditional for loop instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < navnBlirCharArray.length; i++) {
    if (navnBlirCharArray[i] == 'a') {
        navnBlirCharArray[i] = 'A';
    }
}

System.out.println(new String(navnBlirCharArray));
```

I assume this is just a learning exercise, otherwise you could do far simpler with the built in String [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-) method: `System.out.println(navn.replace('a', 'A'));`

Comment: Cheers guys, you are the best. Thank you very much all of you guys!

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting that **output** is a char not an `int`.
so you have to use an `int counter = 0;` and then increment it at every iteration as :

```
private String navn = "Espen Askeladd";

    public void metode4() {
        int counter = 0 ;
        char[] navnBlirCharArray = navn.toCharArray();

        for (char output : navnBlirCharArray) {

            if(output.equals('a')) {     //not navnBlirCharArray
                navnBlirCharArray[counter] = 'A';   //not output(which is character)
            }
            System.out.println(navnBlirCharArray[counter]);  //not output (since you have not changed its value)
       counter++;
        }
    }
```

---

**Edit :**
And also you have to use print(if you want the output in single line rather than multiple Lines